# how to run GWT web application with google app engine server localy

Tags: java, eclipse, google-app-engine, gwt

I have updated eclipse using this [Cloud Tools for Eclips](https://cloud.google.com/eclipse/docs/) and also updated GWT pluings using this [GWT Eclipse Plugin](http://gwt-plugins.github.io/documentation/)

I did all the updation using above links. i did not updated maven integration because mine project is not maven project. now i have created sample GWT web application i can run this using GWT Development mode with jetty then output will come it runs successfully. when i click on run as then i can run this project using development mode and with getty mode and with lagacy mode.
why am i not getting run this project using google app engine server?

how can run gwt sample application with google app enginer server?

Any help

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

See the instructions in the [Cloud Tools for Eclipse → Migrating from the Google Plugin for Eclipse](https://cloud.google.com/eclipse/docs/migrating-gpe#gwt_wzxhzdk2wzxhzdk3).

Comment: Thank you for your valuable response i did as per your instruction when i migrate my gwt 2.6.1 web applcation configure -> conver to app engine server then i am getting some unexpected imports error and i am getting META-INF folder jdoconfig.xml file getting error why this file i am getting what shall i do to solve this

Comment: when i migrated my GWT application configure -> covert to appengine standard then  i have deleted old META-INF folder becuase new one meta inf folder created and i run my application then my application mywarmup class only executed its not executing entry point class why ? any issue ?